# Python version's tmvtnorm::rtmvnorm which original at R

Tags: python, r

For simulating some data, I need to **Sampling Random Numbers From The Truncated Multivariate Normal Distribution**. Which is description of a  function called tmvtnorm::rtmvnorm in R.

I have tried the function in R. But my script is major written by python. So I would like to know **If there are any function could do the same things?**

I have tried **truncnorm in scipy**, **emcee(python libray)**. But it all doesn't work like the result outputed by tmvtnorm::rtmvnorm.

Finally, I am using the *rpy2* to get the result output from R.

Here is the needed question:

1. Any tools which could work like **tmvtnorm::rtmvnorm**?
2. Any explan about the differences of **tmvtnorm::rtmvnorm** and **truncnorm in scipy**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could call `R` from `python` and get the output generated from `rtmvnorm`

```
from pyper import *
import pandas as pd
r=R(use_pandas=True)
r('''
    library(tmvtnorm)
    sigma <- matrix(c(4,2,2,3), ncol=2)
    x <- rtmvnorm(n=500, mean=c(1,2), sigma=sigma, upper=c(1,0))

         ''')
out = pd.DataFrame(r.get('x'))
pr int(out.head(5))
#          0         1
#    0 -0.832567 -1.976393
#    1  0.466617 -0.266892
#    2  0.802809 -0.403514
#    3 -2.295357 -1.896990
#    4 -0.128641 -0.392827
```